# SavefileDialog doesn't show on my C# code

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

everyone. I have a C# code. In my code, savefiledialog can't open, i don't know why. Please help me!

```
public void ReceiveTCP(int portN)
{
    TcpListener Listener = null;
    try
    {
        Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, portN);
        Listener.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    byte[] RecData = new byte[BufferSize];
    int RecBytes;

    for (; ; )
    {
        TcpClient client = null;
        NetworkStream netstream = null;
        Status = string.Empty;
        try
        {                          
             string message = "Accept the Incoming File ";
             string caption = "Incoming Connection";
             MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
             DialogResult result;

             if (Listener.Pending())
             {
                  client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                  netstream = client.GetStream();
                  Status = "Connected to a client\n";
                  result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons);

                  if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                  {
                       string SaveFileName=string.Empty;
                       SaveFileDialog DialogSave = new SaveFileDialog();
                       DialogSave.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
                       DialogSave.RestoreDirectory = true;
                       DialogSave.Title = "Where do you want to save the file?";
                       DialogSave.InitialDirectory = @"C:/";
                       if (DialogSave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                            SaveFileName = DialogSave.FileName;
                       if (SaveFileName != string.Empty)
                       {
                           int totalrecbytes = 0;
                           FileStream Fs = new FileStream
            (SaveFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                           while ((RecBytes = netstream.Read
                (RecData, 0, RecData.Length)) > 0)
                           {
                                Fs.Write(RecData, 0, RecBytes);
                                totalrecbytes += RecBytes;
                           }
                           Fs.Close();
                       }
                       netstream.Close();
                       client.Close();
                  }
             }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            //netstream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you click "Yes" on the Yes/No dialog?

Comment: Is this a console application?

Comment: Yes, I click Yes, but then nothing to show

Comment: This code is for a window app form

Comment: So you click the "Yes" button, and then *nothing* happens? Nothing at all? No Save dialog? No exception? Nothing?

Comment: Yes, nothing at all.